# How to redirect specific URL to Subdomain

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomains, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a `.htaccess` rule to redirect the URL to a subdomain.

Example: `example.com/pagecategory/page-single` → `pagecategory.example.com/page-single`

I've added wildcard subdomain on my hosting.

Can anyone help me write the `.htaccess` code?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `example.com/pagecategory/page-single` to `pagecategory.example.com/page-single`, where `pagecategory` is entirely variable then you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([\w-]+) https://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [R,L]
```

I've limited the "subdomain" (ie. `pagecategory`) to just the lowercase characters `a-z` - this is saved in the `$1` backreference. Likewise, `$2` holds the "page-single".

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Change `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only once you have confirmed it works as required (to avoid browser caching issues).

Comment: With your rewrite script, the original link already switch to subdomain link, but I got 404 http error.

Comment: If you request `pagecategory.example.com/page-single` directly does it work?

Comment: Still got 404.
FYI, I wrote your script at the top of .htaccess file, above the wordpress permalink.

Comment: Well, that would seem to be the problem. If `pagecategory.example.com/page-single` doesn't actually work then redirecting to this is obviously not going to work. (?) You need to change the routing in WordPress itself, so that you can access the site without the _category_ path segment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple 301 redirect in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 <old_url> <new_url>
```

Comment: Although you should generally avoid using mod_alias `Redirect` directives with mod_rewrite (as used by WordPress) because of the potential for conflicts. And if this is a generic redirect as implied in the question (category => subdomain) then you can't do this with a "simple" `Redirect`. (Incidentally, `RewriteEngine` has nothing to do with the `Redirect` directive.)